# Do I have to create a new class for each Kivy Screen? If so, why?

Tags: python, oop, kivy, screen

everybody. How's it going?

I couldn't find any related question to this. If there is any, I would be glad if anyone could reference it and close the thread.

I'm a complete beginner to Kivy, but not to programming. I'm learning python for mobile and webdev purposes.

Python version: 3.8
Kivy version: 2.0.0
IDE: VS Code Community

---

I'm coding this:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder


class LoginPage(Screen):
       pass

class SecondPage(Screen):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file("layout_05.kv.txt")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_file

if(__name__=="__main__"):
    MainApp().run()
```

---

I've seen some tutorials on Youtube, and all of them approach screen creation and management basically the same way. Whether it is just a simplistic way to demonstrated to newcomers or the real thing, I don't really know.

The point is, I'm not an expert on OOP, but I'm studying it. As far as I've reached, it makes much more sense for me that I should go for one and only one class that inherits from "Screen" class (from kivy.uix.screenmanager), and approach screens as objects of same type.

Now, is that the goto way or there's a smarter way to approach deal with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking here. Could you give an example of your proposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a new class for each `Screen`. That is just a convenient way to do it and allows you to build a `kv` rule like:

```
<LoginPage>:
    name: 'login'
    Label:
       text: 'Some text here'
    .
    .
    .
ScreenManager:
    LoginPage:
```

But you can do something like this:

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'login'
        Label:
            text: 'Some text here'
    Screen:
        name: 'screen2'
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, buddy. I couldn't find any post telling which one would be a better practice, but personally I find the latter way more organized and efficient in terms of word typing itself.